# String in code vs string from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings behave differently in IsInRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an appSetting value in my web.config that holds an Active Directory group name. i.e. *"Mydomain\MyAdmin_Group"*

My code checks to see if the user is in the group specified but returns false.

```
User.IsInRole(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminGroup"].ToString())
```

If I use the following code it returns true.

```
User.IsInRole("MyDomain\\MyAdmin_Group")
```

My appSetting in my Web.Config is:

```
 <add key="AdminGroup" value="MyDomain\\MyAdmin_Group"/>
```

Why does the "hard coded" call work but the version using the ConfigurationManager not work?

Comment: Do a runtime test and confirm `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminGroup"].ToString() == "MyDomain\\MyAdmin_Group"`.

Comment: A quick review with a breakpoints and the debugger is great for finding issues like this. Get it right to the point where the code does something unexpected and examine all the relevant variables. Compare them against known good values. The compiler isn't broken there is always a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the double backslash in the config file.  Just use a single one.  Double backslash is only used by c# to escape the backslash character, which has special purposes within string literals.  In fact, if you were coding in VB.NET, e.g., the string literals can use single backslashes because it's not an escape character in VB.NET.